# coreutils ls summary

Tags: command-line, ls, coreutils, unix-philosophy

Why is there no summary option in coreutils `ls` command, like MS-DOS/Windows has?

With summary option I mean:
count the *files* and *dirs* and sum up their *sizes*.

*Update:*

It should read: "*Even* DOS/Windows has one."

It's:

```
command.com  vs.  sh
cmd.exe      vs.  bash
```

with clear points for the latters.

But for some reason, and that is the question, Linux/Unix has *no summary* in the directory listing.

And instead of fixing that, statements go out that this is right and the right thing to do and "well done"... Only after that threads explodes with solutions to fix this vacancy by scripting!

It seams to me a good example of the [**X-Y Problem**](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem):

- User wants to do X.
- User doesn't know how to do X, but thinks they can fumble their way to a solution if they can just manage to do Y.
- User doesn't know how to do Y either.
- **User asks for help with Y.**
- Others try to help user with Y, but are confused because Y seems like a strange problem to want to solve.
- After much interaction and wasted time, it finally becomes clear that the user really wants help with X, and that Y was a dead end.

---

Imagine the following:

You sit in a restaurant, the waiter brings the bill. He has listed all the dishes, but no summary! You have to do it yourself - he has already "well done".

Or hasn't he?

---

*Closing remark*:

Of course know I - and love - the *UNIX toolkit*.  But the basic functions should be provided by the tool itself. To add a few numbers - at the right place, and especially in such a heavily needed case - is no thing. And I see no reason not to do it.

---

*Conclusion*:

My understanding is now: It's **POSIX**!

The [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) standard has no mention of a summary. And that's it.

It's carved in stone.

People don't even think about **X**. They are *used* to dealing with **Y**.

Nevertheless, it is astonishing how completely the possibility that it could also be otherwise is lost from view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the basic functions should be provided by the tool itself.

This is correct. The UNIX/Linux philosophy is *to have commands/tools that do one thing only, and do that thing extremely well*. Then the stdout of one command is fed to the stdin of another, via a pipe, to produce complex results.

The purpose of the `ls` command is, from its manpage, to "list information about files". It is able to produce a listing including or excluding patterns, sorted by different criteria, showing different information, etc. but it's all it does. To calculate the total size of a group of files is not `ls`'s duty. In fact, this is what `du` does. The `du` command, again from its manpage, is a tool to "summarize disk usage of the set of files".

So, this might not be the answer you were looking for, but `ls` behaves like this *by UNIX design*. A design which has proven itself efficient during many decades, I might add.

On the other hand, the philosophy of Windows, as I have noticed, is different. To me, it looks like it aims to provide the user with some general-purpose tool that does a bit of everything, perhaps in the purpose of not having an (inexperienced) user learn too many commands.

Comment: Yes, the *UNIX/Linux philosophy*, the *UNIX toolkit* does great for decades. But that doesn't mean that one or the other tool can't use a little improvement.

Do you want to run: `ls -l` then `du -bc` count the files
`find -type f |wc -l` and the dirs
`find -type d |wc -l`. You have to admit it's annoying. I had a *perl* onliner myself back then: `alias pc='perl -apE '\''++$i and $x+=$F[4] if /^-/;END{$x=~s/(?<=\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+\b)/./g;say" $i Files  $x Bytes"}'\'` `LS_BLOCK_SIZE=1 \ls -l |pc` Until... What the heck? Its **Y**!

Answer (score 1):

`du` is a powerful command to summarize file and directory usage. See https://superuser.com/questions/162749/how-to-get-the-summarized-sizes-of-directories-and-their-subdirectories.

For example `du -sh *` to see the size of each folder. Adding the `-c` option `du -csh *` give a grand total at the end.

File counts can be found by piping ls output into `wc`, as follows, `ls | wc -l`.

Whatever you're trying to do I'm confident there's a way in Linux. It may not be identical to what you're used to in DOS/Windows but in general Linux is much more flexible in what you can achieve.

Comment: This does not count files or directories, which this user explicitly seems to ask for.

Comment: Piping it into `wc -l` will give a file count. My point is that I'm sure there are ways in Linux to provide whatever summary information DOS/Windows provides.

Comment: Yes, `du` and `wc` are the crutches everyone has to use.

Comment: `ls | wc` is a very, very bad way of counting files and [will be wrong in many cases](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). `ls -i | wc` might work a bit better, but really, don't use `ls` for things like this.

Comment: @terdon: Thanks for the link! Here is another one: [X-Y Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) ... fits very well. The scripters are the Y.

Comment: Side note about counting files: [this is how I do it](https://superuser.com/a/1687310/432690).

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a unix/linux utility that could produce an output *similar*  to the `dir` output from `DOS` (I'm using the shot on [this page as a reference](https://www.britannica.com/technology/MS-DOS) as I don't have access now to a Windows machine):

[`tree`](https://gitlab.com/OldManProgrammer/unix-tree)

It can list the contents of the current directory along with a summary *a la DOS* using the following switches:

`-i`     -- don't print indentation lines
`-L 1`   -- set depth level to 1
`--du`   -- report each dir size as the accumulation of sizes of all its files and sub-directories (and their files, and so on as long as it isn't denied to descend in those respective sub-directories by `-L`). The total amount of used space is also given in the final report.
`--timefmt '%D %T'`  -- print and format the date per the format string `%D %T`

so running e.g.

```
tree -i -L 1 --du --timefmt '%D %T'
```

prints

```
[    8499420 12/05/22 21:38:20]  .
[    2028626 12/28/21 13:24:00]  02.jpg
[    4907520 11/08/22 01:54:10]  03.JPG
[       4096 12/05/22 17:38:54]  05-dir
[     465991 11/01/22 21:46:33]  08.jpg
[     418149 11/01/22 21:46:33]  09.jpg
[       4096 11/28/22 20:42:09]  11-dir
[     583732 10/16/22 21:34:43]  16.png
[      83114 02/20/22 23:01:49]  19.jpg

     8499420 bytes used in 2 directories, 6 files
```

Now... there are some differences:

First, there's no way that I know of to print `<DIR>` for directories without post-processing... though `tree` honors the `LS_COLORS` so directories will have different colors if that environment variable is set and output is to `tty`; either way, it's possible to use different colors via `TREE_COLORS` e.g. this is what it looks like on my setup (this time with `-h` added to print sizes in human-readable format):

```
TREE_COLORS="di=1;32" tree -i -L 1 --du --timefmt '%D %T' -h
```

[image]

Note there's also the `-F` which does the same as when used with `ls` e.g. it  appends  a  `/` for directories, a `=` for socket files, a `*` for executable files and so on (consult the manual for details on this and other things like various ways of sorting the files, showing hidden files etc)

Second, `tree` prints the columns in a different order: the size first, then the date, then the file names. Again, without post-processing there's no way to change the order of the columns. As of v. 1.7 `tree` can output JSON -   you could pipe that JSON output to e.g. `jq` and rearrange everything so it's nearly identical to the DOS counterpart but that's beyond the scope of this post which is *"basic functions provided by the tool itself"*

Comment: Yes, I know `tree`. My aliases are: `alias tre='tree --dirsfirst -fhFa'` and `alias tred='tre -d'`. I've learned that the design with POSIX is "tool + post-processing". The tools themselves are untouchable.

Comment: @bashianer Well, good luck then.